# Adding month and date values to an attribute containing only year psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, to-char

Right now I have dates that look like this format(datecreated from table2)

```
 +1999
 +1999
 -0700
 -0480
```

And I want them to look like (inserted into creationdate in table)

```
1999/12/31
1999/12/31
-700/12/31
-480/12/31
```

This is my best attempt so far (the numid and accnum are just to find where the records match)

```
update table set creationdate = to_date('1231'||(to_char((select datecreated from table2 m, table n where m.accnum = n.numid), 'sg9999')),'MMDDSGYYYY');
```

Comment: `format('%s-12-31 %s', abs(datecreated), case when datecreated < 0 then 'BC' end)::date`

Comment: @Abelisto I get this ERROR:  syntax error at or near "format"
LINE 1: format('%s-12-31 %s', abs(datecreated), case when datecreated < 0 th...

Comment: Unfortunately can not say anything without seeing the source code and error message. In any case it was just a suggestion how to simplify the code.