# Encode BC date in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40944531/593144).

Is it possible to encode year, month and day (when year is negative) to the BC date in the simple way, without tricks?

Trying the direct way like

```
select make_date(-11,1,1);
ERROR:  date field value out of range: -11-01-01
```

There are several alternatives like:

```
select make_date(1,1,1) - interval '11 years';
select format('%s-%s-%s BC', '0011','01','01')::date;
```

but obviously it is not the best approach.

So it seems like some kind of bug:

```
select extract(year from '0011-01-01 BC'::date);
╔═══════════╗
║ date_part ║
╠═══════════╣
║       -11 ║
╚═══════════╝
```

but using negative value of the year in the `make_date` function causing the error.

Tested on PostgreSQL 9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that seems like an oddity.

If you can come up with a patch for the pgsql-hackers mailing list, you've got chances to get it fixed.

Comment: It seems (looking to error message, for example `select make_date(1,-1,1);` and `ERROR:  date field value out of range: 1--1-01`) that `make_date` function realized like `cast(format('%s-%s-%s', $1,$2,$3) as date)` which is completely wrong... However bug report posted.